# cakephp $this->request-is("post") return false for just one form, so strange?

Tags: cakephp

I have many forms in the website. They are all created in the similar way like

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SysUser');?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Edit Basic Information'); ?></legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('SysUser.first_name');
echo $this->Form->input('SysUser.family_name',array('label'=>__("Last Name")));
echo $this->Form->input('SysUser.mobile_phone_number');
echo $this->Form->input('SysUser.user_name',array('label'=>__("Screen Name")));
echo $this->Form->input('action', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>'edit_basic_info'));
echo $this->Form->input('SysUser.id', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$user["id"]));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

But the type of one form becomes "put" , not "post". I never explicitly set the type to "post" when I create these forms. I gather CakePHP sets the default value to post. Now it seems something wrong about the way I create this new special form. Oddly, this was working days ago!

I don't know what's wrong. Here is it:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Member'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Basic Profile Setup'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Member.gender_id');
    $w = array();
    for ($i = 40; $i < 120; $i++) {
        $w[$i] = $i . " kg";
    }
    $h = array();
    for ($i = 120; $i < 230; $i++) {
        $h[$i] = $i . " cm";
    }
    echo $this->Form->input('Member.height', array(
        'options' => $h,
        'empty' => __("choose one")
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('Member.weight', array(
        'options' => $w,
        'empty' => __("choose one")
    ));
    $options['minYear'] = date('Y') - 78;
    $options['maxYear'] = date('Y') - 18;
    echo $this->Form->input('Member.birthdate', $options);
    echo $this->Form->input('Member.residential_location_id', array('label' => __("City/Location")));
    echo $this->Form->input('Member.occupation_id',array('id'=>'MemberOccupationId'));
    echo $this->Form->input('action', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 'create_member'));
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php
echo $this->Form->end(array("label" => __('Save')));
```

Answer (score 18):

When the `Request data` contains a Model.id `CakeRequest::method()` is set to `put`. The preferred way to handle this in cakephp would be as follows.

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    // Code
}
```

You can see this in [baked](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) controller, edit actions.

Comment: So basically CakeRequest::is() is accepting array as parameter as well, in this special condition, but not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: not working..have been searching about 12 hours for answer and have no results

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why it is happening, but you can set the form type this way:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Member', array('type' => 'post')); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. In my situation this was happening when I had validation errors. So for the second run, the script thought it was a PUT request instead of a POST request. Now, because it was a PUT, it didn't even get inside the if-clause where I checked if it was a POST, so it would return to the input and try to create a POST request. This was looping forever.

The solution? Checking for a NOT GET.

So you would get something like this:

```
if (!$this->request->is('get')){
    //Save logic here
}
```

I have seen an example like this in the Cookbook, but I can not find it. So I have a feeling it has been updated, but as far as I am concerned you have to use this method. So you will cover a PUT, as well as a POST request.

**UPDATE**

It is not recommended to use this approach. It is a PUT/POST based on if the `id` is set in the form. Since I was setting the id based on the type of request, instead of if it actually exists, it was switching over and over again. I am using 1 form for the `add` and the `edit` action. They both use the `edit.ctp` which is just set up more flexible.

Comment: It will also handle 'DELETE' requests. Probably won't be a problem as those requests will not reach this action. Just for completeness

Comment: Hm now that I think about it, it may also tolerate 'Ajax' requests, so maybe you should stick with what I'm using: if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {}

Comment: @thaJeztah About the Ajax requests, you have a very interesting point there. I think I am going to have a look at my code again and do some testing with my own situation. And try to figure out what the consequences could be.

Comment: it might not be a problem at all, an AJAX request will also use either 'post' or 'get'. I was just thinking out loud. Am interested in your results though!

Comment: @thaJeztah If I take a look at [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request) of the books, I think it would not do any harm. Because a XMLHttpRequest is a POST request as well (correct me if I am wrong, did not verify this) and the `$this->request->is('ajax')` only checks if it is a XMLHttpRequest, at least I think. So in that case both parameters (post and ajax) will evaluate to true. But I have to test this. It is a very interesting case.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution because it's not attacking the cause of the problem.

Comment: @luchomolina Yes it does. Because the FormHelper is interpreting a Form validation error as an edit. So it will become a POST. This is due to the fact that the request object contains data an thus changes the request method.

Comment: It shouldn't work that way. It doesn't work that way in any of the many Cake apps I've built. The framework only changes the method to PUT when the primary key is set in the request data.

Comment: @luchomolina Now, I don't understand it. I understand what you are saying, that is not the point, but I had the exact same problem in my project and there it did not contain a primary key. So I find it very strange why it was happening to me. I think I have to do some more research on this topic and figure out why it happened in my project as well. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Jelmer, exactly! I don't understand what the problem is either, that's my point. We should get to the bottom of this :P

Answer (score 0):

From [the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3acreate):

> If `$this->request->data` contains an array element named after the form’s model, and that array contains a non-empty value of the model’s primary key, then the FormHelper will create an edit form for that record.

Is that the case, perhaps? What's `Member`'s primary key?

Comment: id is the primary key for Member and SysUser.

Comment: I have a signup form without id which is working just fine. This member form is used to create a new member.

Comment: @Jusfeel well, that's very weird, but well, remember you can always set the the type explicitly, as Bill Rollins suggests.

Comment: Also, @Jusfeel, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty, do a deep debugging of the form render. On weird scenarios like this it's always my best bet, as I get to learn a lot about the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after 4 hours searching I just resolved it appending the Model name to the fields in the view like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('User.id');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array('readonly' => true));
    echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array('readonly' => true));
    echo $this->Form->input('User.name');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.phone');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.gender');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.locale', array('id' => 'locale_select', 'options' => array('es' => __('Spanish'), 'en' => __('English'))));
    echo $this->Form->input('User.birthday', array('type' => 'date', 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 100, 'maxYear' => date('Y')));
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Save', true));?>
```

Well, I have to say that this code is in a plugin, so I don't know if there could be any other problems. But other forms in that plugin work perfect and this one needs to have the Model name.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I've handled this situation is to create my own detector that defines the context of post OR put. This goes in the `beforeFilter()` method in AppController:

```
// add a simple form post detector
    $this->request->addDetector('formPosted', array(
    'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
    'options' => array('post', 'put')
));
```

Then when you need to check if a form has been posted (or "putted"), then:

```
if ($this->request->is('formPosted')) { ... }
```

Since the detector is added in AppController, the condition can be checked from within any controller method.